# Why does processing data become a lot slower when implementing a string value?

Tags: python, pandas, python-imaging-library

While trying to process data, as soon as I add the label and give it the value "dog" as example, the processing time increases by so much it makes it impossible to complete my list in a reasonable time.

If I keep the value as an integer, the list takes a few seconds to complete, what's the reason behind that? Is there a way to prevent this issue while still having dog as the label?

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import glob
columnNames = list()
columnNames.append('label')
for i in range(90000):
    pixel = 'pixel'
    pixel += str(i)
    columnNames.append(pixel)


train_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = columnNames)



dogs = glob.glob("data/smallDogs/*.jpg")

for i in range(0, len(dogs)):
    t = i
    img = Image.open(dogs[i])
    rawData = img.load()
    data = []
    data.append(0) # as soon as I append a string value, the processing takes so much longer.
    # data.append('dog')
    for y in range(300):
        for x in range(300):
            data.append(rawData[x,y][0])

    k = 0
    train_data.loc[i] = [data[k] for k in range(90001)]
    print('Processed ', str(i))


print(train_data)
train_data.to_csv("train_converted.csv",index = False)
```

Comment: So you're saying that when the first element of the list is `'dog'`, the code is a lot slower than when it is `0`, with no other changes?  That seems really odd.

Comment: Yeah, it's a dramatic increase too, somewhere along the lines of like 200x slower from what I've estimated.

Comment: Get rid of the initial `append()`, and after the nested x/y loops finish, insert `'dog'` at the beginning.

Comment: Even inserting dog after the nested loop finishes, the same issue occurs.
The issue seems to be when I append it to train_data.

Comment: Because pandas relies on numpy for speed, but numpy is designed to work with numerical data, and you forcing it to use the `object` dtype, which slows everything down. Also, the way you are creating your dataframe is fundamentally slow... But why use pandas here at all? Using pandas just to create a csv  is like using a sledgehammer to swat a fly

Comment: Use `0` for the initial append, then at the end of the loop, reassign `train_data.loc[0] = 'dog'`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you recommend instead?

Comment: Just vanilla python, use the `csv` module.